# Running Angular 5 app in an Angular 6 global environment

Tags: angular

I have decided to install the latest version of Angular 6.1.1 on a new machine. I have a project that uses Angular 5.0.0, which I will copy onto the new machine. I want the project to continue using Angular 5. Does each project use its local CLI, and if so, will my project still run correctly?

I, initially, created the project by installing Angular 5, on my old machine, like:

```
npm install-g @angular/cli@1.5.0
```

The global install path was:

```
C:\Users\[My User Name]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular
```

I intend to install Angular 6, on my new machine to:

```
C:\Users\[My User Name]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular
```

So, all the installation directory paths will be identical.

My Angular projects reside on both machines at:

```
C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot
```

I don't want to upgrade the project because it uses RxJS 5, and I know that Angular 6+, uses RxJS 6, which has some significant differences. And, I think it could well break, even if I apply the RxJS upgrade pack.

Am I right in thinking that whenever I create a new Angular project, it is a self contained unit, that can run anywhere? And, no longer depends on its global environment? So, potentially, I could have several different projects, each using a different version of Angular? Or does each project require the global Angular install in some way?

**Environment:**

Windows 10

**package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
   "rxjs": "^5.5.10",
   ...
}

"devDependencies": {
   "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
   "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
   "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
   "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
   "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
   "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
   "karma": "~1.4.1",
   "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
   "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
   "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
   "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
   "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
   "protractor": "~5.1.0",
   "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
   "tslint": "~4.4.2",
   "typescript": "2.4.2"
}
```

Comment: This is a simple question, true. One you could find the answer to yourself by simply trying to install/build/run the application. The `ng` output in the command prompt will tell you that the local version of the CLI is always used first.

Comment: The reason I have not run it, is because I am concerned it might mess with my global or local Angular settings. But, I guess you have addressed this now, in a round about way!

Comment: *Does each project use its local CLI, and if so, will my project still run correctly* Just check this out. Voting for closing.

Comment: @Antoniossss Thanks for this. Please don't close this. I have got a friend called Max, who will be answering this question within a few days. In the meantime, I will look at the link you have provided. But, I think this could be a useful question for Angular newbies, like myself. Thanks for your help, anyway...

Comment: @Antoniossss I am afraid your link does not work and I did a search on it, and there were no results available.

Comment: @CharlesRobertson no wonder it does not work as I did not provide anything. I guess it should wrote "check that out"...

Comment: _Am I right in thinking that whenever I create a new Angular project, it is a self contained unit, that can run anywhere? And, no longer depends on its global environment?_ - yes, that's correct. All dependencies are installed locally.

Answer (score 1):

To use 2 versions of angular in the same machine I would use the angular CLI localy from your node modules inside your project like this:

```
<project dir>/node_modules/.bin/ng serve
```